# Create Excel sheet with worksheet_change code

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that creates a worksheet and the worksheet contains a table.
I then programmatically add an advanced filter to the table in the created worksheet.
This works fine, but the advanced filter does not refresh on change of the worksheet: A known issue.

The standard solution is to put code behind the `worksheet_change` event so the filter is refreshed when the worksheet changes.  This also works fine when I add this code manually.

But when I create a sheet I want to automatically create the code for the new sheets `worksheet_change` event.  I don't know how to programmatically specify code for my new sheet in the `worksheet_change` event.

Is this possible? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe do it in the workbook instead so you don't need to add it to the worksheet object.

Comment: Or, Create a hidden sheet containing your code (and anything else you want, eg the table). Use that as a template when you create a new sheet

Comment: @braX comment above seems to do the trick.

Comment: I found that the method now linked to this question did not suit my needs after all.  It seems that method causes me to lose all my variables in memory, as if there had been a break in my code.  Perhaps there is a solution to that, but the next answer by @skin is a much better one for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe look at using this instead.  It'll fire for all sheet changes and allows your code to work centrally ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet Change]

Comment: After trying the linked solution that seems to answer my question directly,  I'm going to try this method.  The linked solution has a drawback:  I lose all variables held in memory.

Comment: Yes, this works and is a much better solution for my particular needs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class module with the event and hook that to your worksheets. So you can add a hidden sheet with all workbook names that you want to add that event to.

So if you programmatically add a new sheet you just need to add its name to that list.

So first add a sheet named `MyClassSheets` (you can make it hidden so no user sees it). And add some sheet names there:

[image]

So this means we want to run your `worksheet_change` event in `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` only.

Then we add a class module `MyWsClass`:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Ws As Worksheet

Private Sub Ws_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Address(False, False) & " changed."
End Sub
```

This is the event we want to run. It just shows a message box which cell was changed. You need to adjust that to your wishes.

Finally we need to hook those events to the worksheets. So we add a normal module (non-class module) `HookWsEvents`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyWorksheets() As New MyWsClass

Public Sub HookEvents()
    ' get list of worksheets we want to add the class
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyClassSheets")
        Dim MyClassSheets() As Variant
        MyClassSheets = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    
    ReDim MyWorksheets(UBound(MyClassSheets) - 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    ' add class to those worksheets
    Dim Ws As Variant
    For Each Ws In MyClassSheets
        Set MyWorksheets(i).Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(Ws))
        i = i + 1
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

So now we just need to make sure that the procedure `HookEvents` is called everytime the workbook opens. So we add the following into `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    HookEvents
End Sub
```

After running `HookEvents` the event runs in every sheet that is listed in `MyClassSheets`.

If you now add a new worksheet that you want to add the event to, you just need to add it to the list in `MyClassSheets` and run `HookEvents` again. Therefore we can add a small helper procedure to our `HookWsEvents` module:

```
Public Sub AddWsToList(Ws As Worksheet)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyClassSheets")
        ' add the worksheet name of Ws to the list in MyClassSheets
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value = Ws.Name
    End With
End Sub
```

So now we can use the following code

```
' add a new worksheet as last worksheet
Dim NewWs As Worksheet
Set NewWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))

' give it a name
NewWs.Name = "Sheet5"

' add it to the list of MyClassSheets
AddWsToList NewWs

' hook events to all sheets
HookEvents
```

to add a new worksheet and add the event to it.

You may want to add some error checking if a worksheet in the list of `MyClassSheets` does not exist anymore (was deleted) so your code does not thorw an unhandled exception in this case. I left this out to have the above explanation more clear.

If all your sheets have someting common in their name you don't need to maintain that `MyClassSheets` list. So for example if all the sheets you want to add the event to start with `XYZ_` you just need to loop over all sheets in the `HookEvents` procedure and check if they start with `XYZ_` to add them to the `MyWorksheets` array then. Resizing that array may be a bit more complicated then.